# What terminal emulator is used in LinuxMint 17.2 Rafaela?

Tags: linux-mint

I installed Gnome commander and I can't launch the terminal with shift+enter. On the settings->options->programs tab the terminal appeared to be xterm.
So to what do I change 'xterm' to in order to launch a terminal instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to find out would be to launch the terminal from the GUI or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then going to Help => About on the terminal itself.

Anyway, I think the default on Mint is `gnome-terminal` or `mate-terminal`.